# Error in powershell code for Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script to notify password expiration.

```
$searcher = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher([adsi]"") 
$searcher.filter = "(&(objectclass=user)(objectcategory=person)(mail=*)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))"
$users = $searcher.findall()

Foreach ($user in $users)
{
    $TheUser = $user.GetDirectoryEntry()
    $usuario = $theuser.samaccountname
    $nombre = $theuser.givenname
    $apellidos = $theuser.sn
    $mail = $theuser.mail
    $uac = $theUser.userAccountControl
    $flags = Get-Uac("$uac")

    if ($flags -notcontains "DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWORD")
    {
        [datetime]$PasswordLastChanged = $theuser.PasswordLastChanged
        #$PasswordLastChanged = $theuser.PasswordLastChanged
        $intTimeInterval = [int32]($ahora.days - $PasswordLastChanged.days)  
        
        if ($intTimeInterval -ge $intMaxPwdAge)  
        {  
            [string]$strExpiringDays = "CADUCADA"  
            $avisar = 0  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            $ExpiringDate = $PasswordLastChanged.addDays($intMaxPwdAge)  
            $fechacaducidad = $Expiringdate.toString("dd/MM/yyyy")  
            $ExpiringDays = [int32]($ExpiringDate - $ahora).days  
            $strExpiringDays = "$ExpiringDays dias"
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> The following exception occurred while retrieving the string representation for method "PasswordLastChanged":
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> At line:12 char:1
>
> [datetime]$PasswordLastChanged = $theuser.PasswordLastChanged
>
> CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [],
> ExtendedTypeSystemException
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseMethodToString

Value -67 is displayed and should say "CADUCADA" instead of negative values

Can you help me, please.

Thank you

Comment: Show us how you obtained the `$users` collection

Comment: $searcher = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher([adsi]"")
$searcher.filter = "(&(objectclass=user)(objectcategory=person)(mail=*)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))"
$users = $searcher.findall()

Comment: What is `$theuser.PasswordLastChanged` ? Did you mean `$theuser.pwdLastSet` ? There is no such attribute with name `PasswordLastChanged`.

Comment: And how can I do what you tell me?

Comment: Change `$theuser.PasswordLastChanged` to `$theuser.pwdLastSet`

Comment: Just curious.. Why not use the ActiveDirectory module ?